# Selecting type element within a class in CSS

Tags: css, html, class

Hi I'm trying to style the 'type="radio"' element but i'm having trouble to get to the element in CSS. Please help, Thanks.

HTML

```
<label class="questionLabel"><input class="questionInput" type="radio" name="q4" value="Strongly disagree">
```

CSS

```
.questionnaireInput radio    {

    width: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector (assuming you're after the radio with class name "questionInput"):

```
.questionInput[type=radio]{
    width: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the exact class name with the `.` in front.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

```css
.questionInput {
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<label class="questionLabel"><input class="questionInput" type="radio" name="q4" value="Strongly disagree">
```

Answer (score 0):

use the attribute selector

```
<label class="questionRadio"><input class="questionRadio" type="radio" name="quiz2" value="Male">

.questionRadio[type=radio]{
    width: 15px;
}
```